# how to check number of documents insert in MongoDB with Mongoose in console.log

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just begin to learn how to use MongoDB and Mongoose, So I try to insert some docs in MongoDB running locally, this is how i do it when I use only MongoDB driver :

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
   const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
   const client = new MongoClient(uri);

   async function run() {
     const dbName = client.db("fruitsDB");
 
     try {
       await client.connect();
       
       // I insert the function to insert the docs here
       await insertMultiDocs(dbName, docs);
    
       // Establish and verify connection
       await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
       console.log("Connected successfully to server");
     } finally {
       await client.close();
    }
   }
   run().catch(console.dir);

   // below is the docs I want to insert and the function I use like the MongoDB's
   // documentation.
   const docs = [
       { name: "Ananas", rating: 7, review: "nice fruit"},
       { name: "Prune", rating: 8, review: "Kinda good"},
       { name: "Peach", rating: 7, review: "taste great"},
       { name: "Strawberry", rating: 9, review: "great fruit"}
   ];

   async function insertMultiDocs (client, newList) {
     try {
       const insertManyresult = await client.collection("fruits").insertMany(newList);
       let ids = insertManyresult.insertedIds;
       console.log(`${insertManyresult.insertedCount} documents were inserted.`);
       for (let id of Object.values(ids)) {
       console.log(`Inserted a document with id ${id}`);
       }
     } catch(e) {
       console.log(`A MongoBulkWriteException occurred, but there are successfully processed documents.`); 
       let ids = e.result.result.insertedIds;
       for (let id of Object.values(ids)) {
        console.log(`Processed a document with id ${id._id}`);
       }
      console.log(`Number of documents inserted: ${e.result.result.nInserted}`);
     }
   }
```

Then I get this console.log :

```
4 documents were inserted.
Inserted a document with id 63051aeb6b883a87e46ea895
Inserted a document with id 63051aeb6b883a87e46ea896
Inserted a document with id 63051aeb6b883a87e46ea897
Inserted a document with id 63051aeb6b883a87e46ea898
Connected successfully to server
```

Now I want to try to do the same with Mongoose :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {

  try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB");
    
    const fruitSchema = new Schema({
      name : String,
      rating : Number,
      review : String
    });

    const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);
    
    // I insert the docs here...
    Fruit.insertMany(docs)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

It work, however is there a way to implemente the console.log in Mongoose and loop through each document inserted like the way it did on MongoDB drive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertMany` returns the documents that are added to DB post the validation (if any validations are set in place).

You can just `.length` on it to get the value like this

```
const insertManyresult = await Fruit.insertMany(docs);

console.log(`${insertManyresult.length} documents were inserted.`);
```

Since you have access to all the documents. You can perform any operation of choice (loop over every document, get length etc.)

Read more about `insertMany` [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-insertMany).